# "From your xxx" to begin or in the end?

Tags: grammar

Can anyone tell me which of the following making sense? more used or has correct grammar?

> - From your mobile device, you can now watch and get alerts of what's going on at home.
> - You can now watch and get alerts of what's going on at home from your mobile device.

Comment: Or try: Now your mobile device lets you see what's going on at home and receive event alerts.

Comment: The adverbial clause *from your mobile device* can go at the beginning, the end, or in the middle: *You can now watch and get alerts **from your mobile device** of what's going on at home*. I think this is General Reference (but it's practically *bound* to be a duplicate too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of these two sentences alone, "You can now watch and get alerts of what's going on at home from your mobile device" sounds better.

However, if you've been talking about different capabilities of mobile devices and this is just one more, you could say: "Also from your mobile device, you can now watch and get alerts of what's going on at home."

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

> Now from your mobile device, you can watch and get alerts about what's going on while at home.

or, changing the end: from home.

This gets straight to the main idea of mobile devices, smoothly introduces the new innovation ("now"), and lets the rest make sense. Sorry you got such a late answer.